# Movie with a spirit that looks like a bag trying to kill a group of people when they go outside

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is the info my friend gave me, it's probably old, the spirit has a bag on his head and chokes people, or is visually like a bag

The spirit did kill some of the group and it came from the sky? My friend didn't finish it so this is all the info he has.

Comment: This isn't Rover from "The Prisoner"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygLg-7G0Xp0 As everyone knows, fun starts at 2:30.

Comment: @Kiyu - Welcome to the site. Roughly when did your friend watch this film?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I don't think it's this one

Comment: @LogicDictates , hey thanks!, roughly 13 years ago

Comment: Final Fantasy ? =) https://www.gbhbl.com/game-movie-review-final-fantasy-the-spirits-within-2001/

Comment: "visually like a bag" ... _[The](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_mi_sm) [Blob](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094761/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_mi_sm)_?